# CouchDB counting values from a Document

Tags: count, sum, couchdb, max, min

I want to count numeric values in my document. I have only simple documents.

```
{id: ####,
rev: ####,
"name": "Camera SX",
"colour": "white",
"manufacturer": "Sony",
"rec_limit": 180}
```

I have 420 documents in this structure with difference rec_limit. And I want to sum all rec_limit. How can i do this ? Is there any Map Function?

and how can i get the min rec_limit or max rec_limit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a view that will use such a map function:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.id, doc.rec_limit);
}
```

In combination with the reduce function: "_stats".

For more informations check out the docs: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/

Comment: thats right but what is the reduce function. How looks like the reduce function ?

Comment: @Relaxo I recommend reading the couchdb documentation about views, map and reduce functions, because its fundamental knowledge for using couchdb.